# How to password protect a folder in Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

A client has asked if they can have a folder in my documents locked. Is it possible to do this? I don't think there's a feature but it's worth a try.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by locking? Encryption is possible; access from only one account is possible (and all admins).

Comment: What research have you done on this topic? What sort of environment are they in? Is their drive encrypted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct in that there is no built-in function in Windows and Windows Explorer that handles protecting access to a folder with a password, that is what Windows User Accounts is for.

There are third party software that handles it, but it is better to use Windows User Accounts instead.